# How to access local repo from gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, artifacts

I am trying to build a Java project using Gradle. I have some dependencies (jars) that are in a location of the type: http://internal_domain.location.local:9000/artifacts/repo
How do I specify this in the build.gradle file? Is it under repositories {}?
In the gradle documentation I came across this but doing something similar does not work for me:

```
repositories {
   ivy {
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com/repo"
    resolve.dynamicMode = true
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's a maven repository (judging by the question tags), you should switch `ivy {` with `maven {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your local repo is a maven repo

```
repositories {
    maven {
        // Look for POMs and artifacts, such as JARs, here
        url "http://repo2.mycompany.com/maven2"
        // Look for artifacts here if not found at the above location
        artifactUrls "http://repo.mycompany.com/jars"
        artifactUrls "http://repo.mycompany.com/jars2"
    }
}
```

[Local Archive Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:maven_local)